# What is the probability that call will be answered during $4^{th}$ minute?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I've got a problem

Let

$X$ is the waiting time for a customer's call to be answered by an agent.
If $X$ has the probability density function as given below.

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}&t<0\\0.25e^{-t/4}&\text{if}&t\ge0\end{cases}$$
What is the probability that call will be answered during $4^{th}$ minute?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Have you made any effort to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

$P$ (Call will be answered during $4^{th}$ minute)

$$\displaystyle=P(3\le x\le4)=\int\limits_{3}^{4}f(t)\mathrm dt\\\int\limits_{3}^{4}f(t)\mathrm dt=\int\limits_{3}^{4}0.25e^{-t/4}\mathrm dt\\=0.25\left[\int\limits_{3}^{4}e^{-t/4}\mathrm dt\right]=0.25×\left[\dfrac{e^{-t/4}}{-1/4}\right]_{3}^{4}\\=-1×[e^{-1}-e^{-3/4}]\\=0.4724−0.3679=0.1045\\\therefore P(3\le x\le4)=0.1045$$